# How to send JSON data via POST (Ajax) and receive JSON response from Struts 2 action

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I am trying to understand how to use JSON and in the process I'm trying to get a JSON response from Struts2 action and display an alert for the response. For this I'm using Ajax POST in JavaScript as follows:

```js
function checkButtonClick(id){  

        var btnSave = 'saveAttendees';  
            var atNameList = $('#attName'+id).val();
            var ptNameList = $('#postName'+id).val();
            var aId = $('#at_id'+id).val();
            
            alert("here");
            var arr = {buttonName:  btnSave,
                    attendeesNameList: atNameList,
                    attendeesPostList: ptNameList,              
                    hidden_At_id: aId
                    };
            $.ajax({                            
                data: arr,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',               
                url:"meeting_record_form",
                
                success:function(result){
                    alert(result.myMsg);
              },
                error:function(result){
                    alert("error");
              }
            });
}
```

My `Action` class contains a `String` field that I'm trying to display in alert as JSON response. But I'm finding problem doing this. What am I missing or doing wrong?

**My action class is as follows:**

```java
private String myMsg;

    public String getMyMsg() {
        return myMsg;
    }

    public void setMyMsg(String myMsg) {
        this.myMsg = myMsg;
    }

private String updateAttendeesRecord() {
        
        
        meetingRecordService.updateAttendeesRecord(attendeesListMethod(), meeting_record);
        setMyMsg("Update Successful!");
            return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**`struts.xml` file:**

```xml
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default, json-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
      <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>
    
    <action name="meeting_record_form" class="com.task.action.MeetingRecordAction" method="updateAttendeesRecord">
     <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

**My `pom.xml`:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Could you provide some info what exactly happens?

Comment: @mic4ael: the updateAttendeesRecord() method runs successfully and data is updated successfully but I either get "error" alert or "undefined"

Comment: Maybe try to add : `async : false` in your `$.ajax`

Comment: @mic4ael: async: false didn't work

Comment: Could try `data: encodeURI(arr)`

Comment: Try to alert the error message from the error callback.

Comment: @mic4ael: I get Message undefined error. and in firebug console i get 500(Internal Server error) o.extend.ajax jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by adding myMsg on the json result. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

In the action configuration you should not override the default configuration from `json-default` package just extend it and all. Also `json-default` extend a `struts-default`, so multiple inheritance is not required.

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default">
  <action name="meeting_record_form" class="com.task.action.MeetingRecordAction" method="updateAttendeesRecord">
    <result name="success" type="json" />
  </action>
</package>
```

Comment: @coding_idiot Thanks for pointing out json-default extends struts-default

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your Action class MeetingRecordAction, method **updateAttendeesRecord** is private, it should be public

```
public String updateAttendeesRecord() {
    meetingRecordService.updateAttendeesRecord(attendeesListMethod(), meeting_record);
    setMyMsg("Update Successful!");
        return SUCCESS;
}
```